# using d3.js to store a svg line chart as an image on the client side

Tags: svg, d3.js, blob

```
d3.select("#save").on("click", function(){
  var html = d3.select("svg")
        .attr("version", 1.1)
        .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
        .node().parentNode.innerHTML;

  //console.log(html);
  var imgsrc = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+ btoa(html);
  var img = '<img src="'+imgsrc+'">'; 
  d3.select("#svgdataurl").html(img);

});
```

this is the code but its not showing the copied image at all. what is the problem?
this is the code from http://techslides.com/save-svg-as-an-image/ . my line chart has mouse over and mouse click actions. i want to convert the chart as an image at the client side without server interaction. this link is the most suitable way but unable to replicate it for my chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is amiss in your port of it...here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZxEA3/) with the code in question and it works.

```
<div id="svg"></div>
<button id="save">Save as Image</button>
<div id="svgdataurl"></div>
```

Comment: ive included the code which u have given too but i shows a small thumbnail but not the image

Comment: for console.log(img) i get a url n when i click on it. i get a black and white image of the graph in a very bad way and with a error as This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 1190: Namespace prefix xlink for href on a is not defined
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle showing your code? I was assuming you did not have the basics working but it seems that your problem is further down the road...

Comment: my code accesses a php file which retrieves data from a db. so i cant create a fiddle.

Comment: can you show the code segment where you are using the namespace prefix xlink?

Comment: the graph i am using is similar to https://leanpub.com/D3-Tips-and-Tricks/read#leanpub-auto-setting-up-the-margins-and-the-graph-area

Comment: i added a d3.ns.prefix.xlink= "http://www.w3.org/2000";
and now when i ipen the link for the image it shows "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below."

Comment: @user3300373 The code you're working on only copies the HTML/SVG code, not any CSS, which is why your shapes are all black.  So either all your styles have to be inline, or else your `<style>` element has to be copied as well.  [This fiddle does that](http://jsfiddle.net/ZxEA3/1/); it will work if you only have one `<style>` block in your page; for an external style sheet, you'll also have to change the link attribute to "xlink:href" from "src".  As for the xlink namespace, I managed to get it added but the solution is a little bit hacky.

Comment: Every true developer has a hacker side to him/her. Thanks for helping out @AmeliaBR!

Comment: Hack-y solutions have their place, I agree, but usually for working with closed-source programs.  If I was a true committed open-source developer, I'd be writing the patch and making a pull request to fix it!

Comment: thank you @AmeliaBR once again :) i got the image but the x axis and y axis lales are not being extracted along with the line graph. its the same code as in https://leanpub.com/D3-Tips-and-Tricks/read#leanpub-auto-adding-axis-labels. what is the problem? the code is same as in the link given. my labels are rotated as in the link

Comment: @user3300373  Not sure what's going on there.  I have the same problem within the fiddle, but when I click on the image to open it in a new tab the text shows no problem.  http://jsfiddle.net/ZxEA3/2/

Comment: @user3300373 Figured it out: text was being rendered, but with tiny font for some reason.  Explicitly setting the text size in the style element made it work: http://jsfiddle.net/ZxEA3/3/.  Also changed so that the style element is a copy, not the same element; not sure if that makes much of a difference.

Comment: @AmeliaBR can u check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23058491/how-to-update-the-markers-of-a-multi-line-on-a-brush